# How to format value of the React Select

Tags: reactjs, react-select, react-final-form

I use "react final forms" and "react select".

I've organized an interface and functionality works, but I have one thing which I don't like.

React select requires options in next format:

```
const options = [
  { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
  { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
  { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }
]
```

and the value also should be set as { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' }.

But for me is strange to have in my model of data (and send to the server also) the value like this - { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' }, because I need only 'chocolate'.

Easy way is format the object into a single value after the form will be saved and format back from single value to the object before the rendering of the element. I know how to do it outside of form, but in this case I should solve this problem again and again for each select element separately.

What I would like to do:

1. Find a way how to set value of the react select as single value, like 'chocolate' instead of object.

OR

2. Create a wrapper for react select component and format value there when it sets (it's easy) and when the form get the value from this field (this I don't know how to do).

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method 1

With strings:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Select from "react-select";

const data = ["1", "2"];

function SingleStringReactSelect() { 
  const [option, setOption] = useState();
  return (
    <section>
      <Select 
        onChange={option => setOption(option)}
        value={[option]}
        getOptionLabel={label => label}
        getOptionValue={value => value}
        closeMenuOSelect={false}
        options={data}
      />
    </section>
  );
}
```

Method 2:

Created example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-z57ke

You can use map in options and with Wrapper like SingleValueReactSelect

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

const data = ["chocolate", "strawberry", "vanilla"];

export function SingleValueReactSelect(props) {
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState();
  return (
    <Select
      {...props}
      value={selectedItem}
      onChange={item => {
        setSelectedItem(item);
        props.onChange(item.value);
      }}
      options={props.options.map(item => ({ label: item, value: item }))}
    />
  );
}

export default function AppDemo() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <p>SingleValueReactSelect Demo</p>
      <SingleValueReactSelect
        isClearable
        isSearchable
        options={data}
        onChange={item => {
          alert(item);
        }}
      />
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your example helps me to format value from string to object in the wrapper of element. I wrote above that it's easy, so I can do it by myself. But when I'm changing the value of the select it returns object, but I need a string. How to force the select return the string - it's a question.

Comment: It's custom onChange callback, as I wrote above, I use react final forms. When form submits, it receives value from select by itself and there is object.

Comment: Added In answer with strings and without wrapper

Comment: Method #1 with strings works for me, thanks a lot for your efforts! Nice hack with label. You saved me a lot of time and let me avoid duplication of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can **transform/filter** the object data once you are sending the form data to server or another component.

Setting the value of the react-select as a single value ***will not show it as selected*** in the React-Select.

Comment: I don't like this approach, because then I need to handle each value separately.

Answer (score 0):

```html
    getOptionLabel={option => option["your query"]}
     getOptionValue={option =>option["your query"]}
```